# How can I open a text file and assign it's contents to a variable in a Python function?

Tags: python, file

[image]I have a text file called `inputs.txt` thats in a folder called `task1` the input file contains a series of strings that I need to process in a Python function.

I need to write a function that can open this `intputs.txt` file and assign the the string contents to the a variable `S`

So far I've got:

```
def open_func(task1/test-input.txt):   # syntax error thrown here with forward-slash
    S = open(task1/test-input.txt, "r")
    print(S)
    return S
```

But this throws a syntax error at the forward-slash

The input file currently contains acbcbba, which I want to be passed to the variable S

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

I've attached a screen shot of the solution I've tried but I'm still getting the "no file or directory test-input.txt" error

Cheers

Comment: `task1/test-input.txt` should be in quotation marks. Also use `context managers` with a `with`.

Comment: You forgot the directory (the `task1/`) before the filename. The error says it explicitly: there is no file named `test-input.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in here:

1. What is inside the parenthesis in the definition must be a parameter, not a string (so replace that `task1/test-input.txt` by something like `file` or `filename`, because `task1/test-input.txt` is what you are trying to open, not a parameter to the function). OR
2. If you want to open a file named `task1/test-input.txt` you need to surround it by quotes (either simple or double, I personnaly prefer double), so `"task1/test-input.txt"`
3. the `open` function opens a *file handle*, not the content of the file. You need to call `read()` on the handle, then `close()` it. So something like:

   ```py
   file = open(filename, "r")
   S = file.read()
   file.close()
   print(S)
   return S
   ```
4. Also, you should use the `with` syntax as pointed out in the comment, which simplifies the above to (since that automatically `close`s the handle):

   ```py
   with open(filename, "r") as file:
       S = file.read()
   print(S)
   return S
   ```

Comment: Okay thanks, when I call the `open_file` function should the file name also be in quotation marks?

Comment: If you passed it in a parameter and as a string literal (so not a variable), then yes. Otherwise you can only ever open that one file you put in the function (and you can't change the file you open).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a filename variable to pass to the function. To do that you declare a variable with its value encapsulated by quotes like this:

```
def open_func(filename):
    f = open(filename, "r")
    content = f.read()
    f.close()
    print(content)
    return content

path = "task1/test-input.txt"
content = open_func(path)
# do something with the file content now
```

Regarding EDIT: The file you are opening needs to be in an accessible path from where you run your script. So if your folder structure looks like this:

```
task1/
    script.py
    test-input.txt
```

You need to call from this path, if you call your script from within "task1/":

```
path = "test-input.txt
```

To get your working directory, you can use this snippet to find out:

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

Comment: Do you mean I should remove the `task1` from my filepath? Becasue this just results in the same Error?

Comment: @Mike5298 Yea, that is what I meant. Hm ok, where do you run your pyhton script from? In which folder are you when you call "python solution.py"?

Comment: It's a uni test in Codility, I'm in task1 when I run `solution.py`

Comment: @Mike5298 Ok this seems strange to me then, are you shure that your unit test framework does not change its execution path somehow? Because that is how it looks like to me. If you use this snippet, you can print your current working directory: 
`import os;

print(os.getcwd())`